# Typescript record assumes full coverage

Tags: typescript

Why is the following [code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQEqonATgEwAoBKRAbwFgAoRRXdEXJSm2xAIwC5EByAQwE8ANNVoBfahKo4wAZyiJZcALaosOAt3V58AHnm4YYZEMVRDxgHyIAvCnTaCJANzVqM%20Yj6JuBo8ltFFTVsHQBtfh4AXVcqdwRPdkC%20ADoAG1RjKAALWPi5OAz0uGRCdmI8qiA) is typescript is legal and yields no warning (or maybe I'm missing something)

```
function getRecord() {
  return {
    b: 'aaa',
  }
}
const someRecord: Record<string, string> = getRecord();

const a : string = someRecord['a'];

const b = a.length;

console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are assigning return value of `getRecord()` to `someRecord` whose type is `Record<string, string>`, which means that it will be an object where `keys` and `values` are of type `string`.

```
const someRecord: Record<string, string> = getRecord();
```

So `someRecord['a']` satisfy the type

```
const a : string = someRecord['a'];
```

To get correct type, Let `TS` infer it and use it as below:
[TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQEqonATgEwAoBKRAbwFgAoRRXdEXJSm2xAIwC5EByAQwE8ANNVoBfahKrUA9DMQYAogFkA8gDVFiACoBNAApaAEoqVCdAZUQB1AJIAZe4lsA5AGKnqOMAGcoiHzgAW1QsHAJEAF4UdDC8ImIAbmovBD9EPkRuP1wYMGQogODQ7HiAbX4eAF1k6SpvdPZCvgA6ABtUfKgAC1rU3zgO9rhkQnYklLrqIA)

```
function getRecord() {
  return {
    b: 'aaa',
  }
}

// REMOVE TYPE HERE, TS WILL INFER
const someRecord = getRecord();

const a : string = someRecord['a'];
//                 ^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-
//                 Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"a"' can't be used to index type '{ b: string; }'.
//                 Property 'a' does not exist on type '{ b: string; }'.(7053)

const b = a.length;

console.log(b);
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I run the code and encounter these errors:

> [ERR]: "Executed JavaScript Failed:"
> [ERR]: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

In the code, there is no 'a' property in the `someRecord` object, accessing it will result in `undefined`. Therefore, trying to get the length of `a` will also result in `undefined`.